# How to read file line by line stored on blobstore of GAE in java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have used code given in following link for uploding the file on blobstore
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

Comment: You have to be more precise about the exact step blocking you. This question is too vague or too broad so it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the sample given in the link you posted?

```
 // Later, read from the file using the file API
      lock = false; // Let other people read at the same time
      FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(file, false);

  // Again, different standard Java ways of reading from the channel.
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));
      String line = reader.readLine();
  // line = "The woods are lovely dark and deep."
```